# how to remove apostrophes that contain a word?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a list that goes something like:

```
list = [" I wish I was Alex's best 'friend' "]
```

I want to remove the apostrophe that contains friend but not the apostrophe that is used in Alex's, If I try this with re.sub like so:

```
list = re.sub('\'\')', '', list)
```

it removes all the apostrophes which I don't want, how can I achieve this so that the result is:

```
list = [" I wish I was Alex's best friend " ]
```

Comment: how are you supposed to know it's `'friend'`, but not `'s best '`? (This is a hint.)

Comment: also, this is a `str` not a `list`, so removing the wrong tag.

Comment: oh so you mean I do re.sub('\ ' ' \ ') ?

Comment: also, naming your variable the same as the type is not very recommended

Comment: ofcourse my variable wouldn't be named like that, I just named it 'list' for question purposes lol I thought that's pretty obvious

Comment: it's not obvious, it's quite confusing. In fact, it's wrong. You don't apply regexes to lists, but to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming apostrophes are only around a single word at a time and not a full sentence, you can use this:

```py
re.sub(r"'(\w+)'", "\1", your_string)
# your_string can be strings from your list if you iterate over it
```

This will catch words surrounded by apostrophes, and remove these apostrophes. Therefore, if there's only a single apostrophes as in `Alex's` or `it's`, it won't remove them.

Please be aware this will not always work, for example if there are apostrophes around `Alex's`, there's no way to know which apostrophe to remove (there is, but it wouldn't be handled by this regex)

### Update

You can make use of a greedy (> 0) quantifier and an alternate statement in order to remove apostrophes around `Alex's`:

```
re.sub(r"'((?:\w|')+)'", "\1", your_string)
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I would like to ask you something, now what if I specifically want to remove an apostrophe that's at the start of the word but not any other apostrophes, for example 'word ?

Comment: update : mark's answer also works for this ^

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
re.sub(r"(?<![a-zA-Z])'(.*?)'(?![a-zA-Z])", r'\1', list[0])
```

This looks for an apostrophe, followed by anything, followed by another apostrophe, as long as there isn't a letter just before the first apostrophe or just after the last one.

Comment: this won't work if there's apostrophes around the last/first word

Comment: true! I'll update it